How to compute the 3D circle given points with known uncertainties
I have a set of measurements of points in 3D $(x,y,z)_i$. These measurements have known uncertainties, which are given as a covariance matrix $C_i$ (an ellipsoid of uncertainty) which represents the 3D standard deviation of the normal distribution of probability of the true location of the point.
I want to compute the center, radius and normal direction vector of the 3D circumference the points lie on, and also compute the associated uncertainties, as propagated by the initial points uncertainties.
I can imagine some least-squares would help obtain the mean values for the center, radius and normal direction vector, given the positions of the measurements. How would I take into account measurement uncertainties and compute the results uncertainties?
